# Contingency table in Shiny with option to either enter group or total values and validate input

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a contingency table in Shiny. I am using `numericInput` and some CSS to make a functional table, and currently am using `verbatimTextOutput` to give row and column totals.

This works, but what I would like to do is to be able to enter numbers into any of the boxes (including the totals) and have it correct the rest. So, for instance, one could enter text into the outcome positive and total columns, and automatically have it fill in the outcome negative column. I haven't found a nice way to get this working with the validation. Any help would be appreciated.

```
(ui.r)
fluidRow(strong("Contingency Table")),
        fluidRow(helptext("Input the ")),
        
        fluidRow(column(width = 3),
                 column(h5("Outcome Positive"), width = 3),
                 column(h5("Outcome Negative"), width = 3),
                 column(h5("Total"), width = 3)),
        
        fluidRow(column(h5("Intervention"), width = 3),
                 column(numericInput(inputId = "int_pos",
                                     label = NULL, 
                                     value = 117,
                                     min = 0),
                        width = 3),
                 column(numericInput(inputId = "int_neg",
                                     label = NULL, 
                                     value = 138,
                                     min = 0),
                        width = 3),
                 column(verbatimTextOutput("int_tot"),
                        width = 3)),
        
        fluidRow(column(h5("Control"), width = 3),
                 column(numericInput(inputId = "con_pos",
                                     label = NULL, 
                                     value = 109,
                                     min = 0),
                        width = 3),
                 column(numericInput(inputId = "con_neg",
                                     label = NULL, 
                                     value = 145,
                                     min = 0),
                        width = 3),
                 column(verbatimTextOutput("con_tot"),
                        width = 3)),
        
        fluidRow(column(h5("Total"), width = 3),
                 column(verbatimTextOutput("tot_pos"), width = 3),
                 column(verbatimTextOutput("tot_neg"), width = 3),
                 column(verbatimTextOutput("tot_tot"), width = 3))
      ),
```

[image: Contingency Table]

```
server.R
  output$int_tot = renderText({
    input$int_neg + input$int_pos
  })
  
  output$con_tot = renderText({
    input$con_neg + input$con_pos
  })
  
  output$tot_pos = renderText({
    input$int_pos + input$con_pos
  })
  
  output$tot_neg= renderText({
    input$int_neg + input$con_neg
  })
  
  output$tot_tot = renderText({
    input$int_neg + input$con_neg + input$int_pos + input$con_pos
  })
```

Comment: So essentially you're wanting to treat the table as both an input and an output?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Would be nice to either enter the total positive and negative and have it sum a total, or add the total positive and the total and have it autofil the negative (as that is how they are usually reported in trials).

Comment: as far as I know, there isn't really a such thing as a ```tableInput()```. I think your best approach would be to continue on your current path - making a bunch of ```numericInput``` or ```textInput``` boxes, then put them together in such a way that looks like a table. Sorry that isn't very helpful, but Shiny does have its limitations.

Comment: That's still helpful to know; and it's not mission critical so happy to accept that limitation. Cheers.

Comment: just came across this [rhandsontable](https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/#Introduction) library. It can be implemented within Shiny (the section for that is at the bottom).